# How to get each value from hash of array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a hash of array with key, values in ruby which I want to pass each value with key. I want to extract content using my hash.  My code is :

```
    def get_content
       GetPageContent.new(@pdf.id, session[:selected_pages][@document.id.to_s])
    end
```

in `session[:selected_pages]` I got like this

```
 {"15"=>["001"], "24"=>["001","005"]}
```

In this first value is `pdf id` and second value is page number of that pdf.

I want this :

```
GetPageContent.new(@pdf.id, session[:selected_pages][@document.id.to_s])
```

I want to pass all values like this:

```
GetPageContent.new(15, 001)
GetPageContent.new(24, 001)
GetPageContent.new(24, 005)
```

How to map each key values from hash of array?

Comment: just loop through it with `.each`

Comment: I have already tried that. i want first values from hash key as first argument in my method and second values from each key as second argument. 
15 and 24 are pdf id
and 15-->001 where 001 is pages no.
i want to pass 001 as second argument for each pdf .

Comment: while you are getting started with ruby/rails, you must have a loo at the docs of Array, Hash, String methods in ruby, we end up using them in every code

Answer (score 3):

A simple nested loop will suffice:

```
session[:selected_pages].each do |pdf_id, page_numbers|
  page_numbers.each { |page_number| GetPageContent.new(pdf_id, page_number) }
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this

```
hsh = {"15"=>["001"], "24"=>["001","005"]}

hsh.each(&->(page, pages){pages.each{|id| GetPageContent.new(id, page)}})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this to get a simple array. `h` is your hash

```
pages = h.flat_map { |key, arr| ([key] * arr.size).zip(arr) }
 => [["15", "001"], ["24", "001"], ["24", "005"]] 
pages.map! { |pdf_id, page_number| GetPageContent.new(pdf_id, page_number) }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
session[:selected_pages]
.map{|k, v| [k].product(v)}.flatten(1)
# => [["15", "001"], ["24", "001"], ["24", "005"]]
```

The rest is up to you.